# Can DotNetNuke 5 work with SQL Server web edition

Tags: sql-server, dotnetnuke-5

I'm trying to move the company's site to a new hosting, and they have SQL Server Web Edition, Can DotNetNuke work with that SQL version? Also, I'm currently using SQL Server Standard Edition.

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't. The [system requirements](http://www.dnnsoftware.com/Platform/Start/Install#2047) page says it runs on SQL Server Express, so Web Edition should be no different.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It will work fine.

Once you get it setup you'll probably want to follow this upgrade path:
http://www.dnnsoftware.com/wiki/page/Suggested_Upgrade_Path

DNN 5 is pretty old.  When you go from 6 to 7 you'll need to switch to .NET 4